# Click browser back button and partial view is no longer displayed?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, browser

I have a view with a table that has a link. When the link is clicked JQuery loads a  PartialViewResult via ajax. The problem is when a user clicks a link within the results displayed in the partial view and goes to another page then clicks the back button, the content of the partial view that was rendered on the original page **is NO LONGER on the page**. How do I get the rendered partial view to be displayed if a user clicks the browser back button?

JQuery...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function getGroup(id) {
     var link = "Search/GroupDetails/" + id;
     $('#Group').load(link);
     $('#Group').show();
 }
```

This is loaded into a DIV

```
 <div id="Group">
 </div>
```

Controller Partial View

```
        public PartialViewResult GroupDetails(string id)
    {
        SearchIndexViewModel newSIVM = new SearchIndexViewModel();
        id = Help.FormatID(id);
        CCRUser ccrUser = _CCRUser.GetUser();
        newSIVM.CCRUser = ccrUser;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            newSIVM.Selected_Group = _Groups.GetSingleGroup(id, cUser);
            newSIVM.Group_Owner = _Groups.GetGroupOwner(id, cUser);
            newSIVM.Group_Members = _Groups.GetGroupMembers(id, cUser);        
            HttpContext.Session["SELECTEDGROUPNAME"] = id;

        }

        return PartialView("_GroupDetails", newSIVM);
    }
```

Comment: Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a document.ready function in your script. This will get fired every time when you load the original view. (I checked and it gets fired even if you press the back button)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Check the session value from the server by sending a ajax request. 
    // You can use the success function of the ajax request to call the get group function
    // If a SELECTEDGROUPNAME exists
    getGroup(1);

});
```